# Getting EduTool to work for Kotlin in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin by following the tutorial. I managed to get the plugin installed in Intellij. But I am not able to get the first exercise to run. When I click on the little checkbok it tells me

> Failed to launch checking. See idea.log for more details.

(I created another blank project and type the same simple exercise in a scratch file and it works.)

[link to docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/education/learner-start-guide.html?section=Introduction%20to%20Java)

Comment: Please share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Koans with EduTools plugin: "Failed to launch checking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729953/kotlin-koans-with-edutools-plugin-failed-to-launch-checking)

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the project's is linked to the right JDK. Open File/Project Structure/Project. Then select the correct Project SDK.

To me, this helped. But as others have pointed out, please, share your idea.log, which you can find at Help/Show log in [whatever text editor it's associated with].