# "Logging in Python" with EduTools Plugin: "Failed to launch checking"

Tags: python, pycharm

## What had happened?

I'm trying to follow the [Logging in Python](https://stepik.org/course/3215/promo) Tutorial in PyCharm Professional.

I'm using a `Virtualenv` environment with Python 3.9.5 in this tutorial. Everything works fine, but when I press "*Check*" button in the **Task Description** panel, I get this error:

> Failed to launch checking. For more information, see [the Troubleshooting guide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-edutools/docs/troubleshooting-guide.html#failed_to_launch_checking).

But when I switch to **Run** panel, all tests are passed with these outputs:

```
C:\Users\Dragon1573\Repos\EduTools\Logging_in_Python\.idea\VirtualEnvironment\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\Dragon1573\Repos\EduTools\Logging_in_Python\Basics\Log output\tests.py" "C:\Users\Dragon1573\Repos\EduTools\Logging_in_Python\Basics\Log output\log_output.py"
Testing started at 21:56 ...
#educational_plugin test_is_not_empty test OK
#educational_plugin test_answer_placeholders_text_deleted test OK
#educational_plugin test_file_importable test OK
#educational_plugin test_answer_placeholders test OK

Process is terminated，exit code is 0.
```

I visits the guide, but it only shoots Java & Kotlin & Scala.

## Versions of the environment?

- Windows 10 Home China 21H1 (version 19043.985)
- PyCharm 2021.1.1 (Professional Edition)
- EduTools Plugin (version 2021.5-2021.1-713)

## Error Logs?

The following contents are logged by PyCharm itself in `idea.log` file. It may be useful.

```
2021-05-29 21:56:42,453 [15968661]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Testing failed although no failed tests found 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Testing failed although no failed tests found
    at com.jetbrains.edu.learning.checker.EduTaskCheckerBase.toCheckResult(EduTaskCheckerBase.kt:119)
    at com.jetbrains.edu.python.learning.checker.PyTaskChecker.areTestsFailedToRun(PyTaskChecker.kt:66)
    at com.jetbrains.edu.learning.checker.EduTaskCheckerBase.check(EduTaskCheckerBase.kt:98)
    at com.jetbrains.edu.python.learning.checker.PyTaskChecker.check(PyTaskChecker.kt:54)
    at com.jetbrains.edu.learning.actions.CheckAction$StudyCheckTask.localCheck(CheckAction.java:251)
    at com.jetbrains.edu.learning.actions.CheckAction$StudyCheckTask.run(CheckAction.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-05-29 21:56:42,454 [15968662]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - PyCharm 2021.1.1  Build #PY-211.7142.13 
2021-05-29 21:56:42,454 [15968662]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 11.0.10; VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2021-05-29 21:56:42,454 [15968662]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Windows 10 
2021-05-29 21:56:42,455 [15968663]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Plugin to blame: EduTools version: 2021.5-2021.1-713 
2021-05-29 21:56:42,455 [15968663]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action: ShowLog
```

This issue is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729953/kotlin-koans-with-edutools-plugin-failed-to-launch-checking), but caused with different reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the [Chinese ​(Simplified)​ Language Pack](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13710-chinese-simplified-language-pack----) enabled in your PyCharm Professional 2021.1.1? If so, please try disabling it and opening the course once again.

There's a [compatibility issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/EDU-4323) between mentioned language pack and Python courses in the EduTools plugin, and the developers are currently investigating it.

I would advise adding this issue to your watch list to be 100% sure that you won't miss any updates.

Comment: Yes, I'm from People's Republic of China using Chinese (Simplified) Language Pack installed and enabled. I disabled it and restart PyCharm, and there's no errors with those tasks! 
Thank you very much ~ (●'◡'●)